# What is the pure Kotlin alternative to 'javaClass'?

Tags: kotlin

I'm implementing a pure Kotlin library that I will be releasing under an open source license. In my library I have, say, `class A`, in which I want to override `equals()`. I used Android Studio's auto-generator to do this, but it included a reference to `javaClass`:

```
override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
   if (this === other) return true
   if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false
   other as A
   ...
}
```

Is this reference safe to use in a pure Kotlin library? What will be the effect if somebody used my library to target, say, JavaScript? Is there a pure-Kotlin alternative to `javaClass`? I'd like to avoid something like

```
if (other !is A) ...
```

because I don't want subclasses of A to register.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did is not safe. The reason Android Studio generated this code, is because you're not developing a multiplatform project, actually.

Multiplatform version would look like this:

```
override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    if (this === other) return true
    if (other == null || this::class != other::class) return false
    return true
}
```

If your goal is to have a platform-agnostic library, develop it as multiplatform project, and put most of your code under `common` module.

Comment: I am developing but Android Studio is not developing a multiplatform class. Most of my work up to now has been in `vi`, but I decided to work in AS for a little for the syntax completion, etc. Your suggestion looks good - I didn't know about `::class`. Thanks!